# Camel JAXB marshalling return XML object type?

Tags: apache-camel

I am sending a Java object to producer endpoint and waiting for the marshalled XML object. I tried changing it to `Node` object/ File object but it is giving `ClassCastException`.

So took the xmlObj in an object class type. What should be the correct class to capture the response?

```
public class ClientEight {

    @Produce(uri = "direct:invoice")
    ProducerTemplate template;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/camel-configTen.xml");
        InvoiceXml invoice = new InvoiceXml("fdf3443", 3454, 435345.44 f, "hfhfddfdg"); //any java object we are passing
        ClientEight client = (ClientEight) ctx.getBean("client");
        Object xmlObj = client.template.requestBody(invoice);
        System.out.println(xmlObj);
    }
}
```

Above is a client code which you are using to send the Java object to a producer endpoint and since you are using `template.requestBody`, you are getting back the object returned.

```
<camel:camelContext>
        <camel:dataFormats>
            <!-- path to jaxb annotated class -->
            <camel:jaxb id="invoiceJaxb" contextPath="com.java.bean"
                prettyPrint="true" />
        </camel:dataFormats>
        <camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="direct:invoice" />
            <camel:marshal ref="invoiceJaxb" />
            <camel:log message=" ${body}" />
            <camel:to uri="file://src/resources?fileName=One.xml"/>
        </camel:route>
    </camel:camelContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `unmarshall` processor return a stream, not a single object. In camel, more generally, if you want a specific type, you shouldn't get directly a body as an object, but use the various methods to convert the body into that type.

Try :

```
Document document = client.template.requestBody(invoice, org.w3c.dom.Document.class);
```

Comment: How would we convert it to xml type?